# Scrapy trouble : UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to enhance my skill in webscraping but I'm stuck with my script. I want to scrape some information on Amazon.

Here's my script so far :

```
import scrapy

from ..items import AmazontutorialItem


class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A1250226011&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1606224210&rnid=1250225011&ref=lp_1_nr_p_n_publication_date_0']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazontutorialItem()

        product_name = response.css('.a-color-base.a-text-normal::text').extract()
        product_author = response.css('.sg-col-12-of-28 span.a-size-base+ .a-size-base::text').extract()
        product_price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-small .a-price-whole::text').extract()
        product_imagelink = response.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name
        items['product_author'] = product_author
        items['product_price'] = product_price
        items['product_imagelink'] = product_imagelink

        yield items

        next_page = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A1000%2Cn%3A1%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A1250226011&dc&page=' + str(AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number) + '&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1606229780&rnid=1250225011&ref=sr_pg_2'
        if AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number <= 3:
            AmazonSpiderSpider += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

But I get this error :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'AmazonSpiderSpider' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand, I never had this error before, even with webscraping.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: AmazonSpiderSpider is the class name, but you’ve not instantiated an instance of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `page_number` from the class `AmazonSpiderSpider` inside the class itself. You are trying to do this with `AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number`, which will most certainly fail. What you were intending to do was probably access `self.page_number`.

The following should fix your issue:

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazontutorialItem


class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A1250226011&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1606224210&rnid=1250225011&ref=lp_1_nr_p_n_publication_date_0']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazontutorialItem()

        product_name = response.css('.a-color-base.a-text-normal::text').extract()
        product_author = response.css('.sg-col-12-of-28 span.a-size-base+ .a-size-base::text').extract()
        product_price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-small .a-price-whole::text').extract()
        product_imagelink = response.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name
        items['product_author'] = product_author
        items['product_price'] = product_price
        items['product_imagelink'] = product_imagelink

        yield items

        next_page = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A1000%2Cn%3A1%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A1250226011&dc&page=' + str(self.page_number) + '&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1606229780&rnid=1250225011&ref=sr_pg_2'
        if self.page_number <= 3:
            self.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: You just forgot the AmazonSpiderSpider in the next_page link but I understood anyway, it works ! Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thanks for telling me and you're welcome!